# Reset old value in a JTable cell when the new one is not correct

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a JTable to enter some numbers ina certain range. When they exceed that range, an exception occurs to show an error. Also when you enter other characters or even you enter nothing.

When those things happen, I want to get the old value back. I have thought to make a listener which warns me when a cell gets focus (I mean when the cell is opened for entering values). Then I would save that value, and if something goes wrong, I have the value ready to be entered again.

I have searched for a while but I haven't seen the way to do that listener yet. How could I do that (or in a different way)?

Comment: We would need to see some code to help you with that. But in general: do i understand correctly that you are using Java Exceptions deliberately when a Field holds an improper value? That would be the wrong way of going about this. So please show us code.

Comment: Yes, I'm throwing a hand-made Exception carrying a message which says what's wrong with the value you just entered. I don't see why this shouldn't be the wrong way of going, please explain. I'm afraind I can't make an small executable example of this. I understand that make answering more difficult, but the name of the listener I need to detect cell focus would be enough help for me right now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Table model (your subclass of `AbstractTableModel`) is expected to do the validation.

When JTable is updated, it performs a call to

```
public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex)
```

Validate the value there, if it does not match the range, just do not update it in your implementation of the model. After setValueAt() is called, the table re-reads the value from model (by a call to `getValueAt()`), so the original content gets back to the table.

Comment: I was about to write the same... Not fast enough. :) Subclassing DefaultTableModel will work too. he just needs `setValueAt()` ...

Comment: yes: the model certainly must protect itself against invalid values. But not the whole story: TableModel has no notion of validation, that is no api to inform if setting was tried but didn't succeed. Such feedback is needed in a well-behaved user interface to inform the user what's wrong and how s/he can get it right, so should be implemented somewhere (custom exception or something else doesn't really matter)

Comment: Kleopatra - right. Actually it should be the TableCellEditor that communicates this to the user (e.g. by not letting them enter invalid values) - I think StanislavL's answer completes the story.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/javax.swing.table/implementsTableCellEditor.htm

See stopCellEditing() 
From the Javadoc:

"Tells the editor to stop editing and accept any partially edited value as the value of the editor. The editor returns false if editing was not stopped; this is useful for editors that validate and can not accept invalid entries."

Answer (score 2):

Here is a much better solution: Use a data model. Your model contains the values.

When the table renders, take the values from your model.

When a user edits a cell, take the current value. When the edit succeeds, put the new value into your model. If the edit fails, just refresh the cell: The renderer will take the unmodified value from your model and you're done.